# How to create USB flash ".bin" image in Linux without physical drive

Tags: linux, filesystems, usb-flash-drive, disk-image

I have some files in Linux, which I have to copy to multiple SD-cards **in Windows** periodically (not bootable, but with file permissions, filesystem `ext3`). Now the procedure is: I copy files to one flash drive under Linux, then create a `.bin` image from this drive and clone this .bin to other USB-drives under Windows. Files sometimes change, so I need to create `.bin` file again. The idea is to create `.bin` files without actually using physical drive.

Is there a solution to create USB-drive images virtually? Or is there a tool to burn ext3 USB-flash drives from `tag.bz2` file under Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to mount the image directly in Linux and make the changes but there is a small problem. These media are partitioned a similar way as a hard drive. The solution is to mount the right partition from the image.

Check that the image is indeed partitioned:

```
$ file -k OpenELEC-RPi.arm-4.95.1.img
OpenELEC-RPi.arm-4.95.1.img: x86 boot sector; partition 1: ID=0xc, active, starthead 32, startsector 2048, 262145 sectors; partition 2: ID=0x83, starthead 146, startsector 266240, 65537 sectors
```

### Working with the image

Map the partitions from the image to loop devices:

```
$ sudo kpartx -av OpenELEC-RPi.arm-4.95.1.img
add map loop0p1 (252:3): 0 262145 linear /dev/loop0 2048
add map loop0p2 (252:4): 0 65537 linear /dev/loop0 266240
```

<sup>On Ubuntu `kpartx` is not installed by default. Do `sudo apt-get install kpartx`.</sup>

Mount the partition:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/tmp1
```

Now make your changes in the `/mnt/tmp1` directory.

Umount the partition and delete the mapping:

```
$ sudo umount /dev/mapper/loop0p1
$ sudo kpartx -dv OpenELEC-RPi.arm-4.95.1.img
del devmap : loop0p2
del devmap : loop0p1
loop deleted : /dev/loop0
```

### Other options

If `kpartx` is not available you can determine the partition offset using for example `fdisk` (It works on images too so you can create the image without having a physical drive at all.) and map them using `losetup` or `mount -o loop,offset=x` or even the new version of `losetup` (from util-linux 2.21) can map the partitions directly using the option `--partscan`.

There are descriptions in other questions:

- [loopback mounting individual partitions from within a file that contains a partition table on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1419489/320437)
- [Mount single partition from image of entire disk (device)](https://askubuntu.com/q/69363/67132)